# How to delete and recreate db manually in migrations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

In laravel 8 app to init database of my app I use migrations with command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

It works ok if my scripts have no  errors, but in case of error(say invalid
fields type in reference to other table) after I fixed error I need to delete and recreate db manually
in phpmyadmin?
If there is a way to auto this process somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: php artisan migrate:rollback this will delete all tables from database .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

With this command it will be drop all tables and re-run migrations

`migrate:refresh` Just reset your tables, not drops.